# How to access the "two" in the below program

Tags: c

Why dont I get `11` in `two`

```c
static struct UDP
{
    char one[10];
    int two;
char three;
};
    
    
int main()
{
    char arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

    struct UDP *ptr;   //Pointer of Structure type
    ptr = (UDP*)arr;
    
    ptr->one;
    ptr->two;
ptr->three;
}
```

Adding anything after two does not point to a proper value... I have casted it
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: One thing to do may have the compiler "pack" the structure not to generate paddings. Another thing is allocating enough elements in `arr` not to cause out-of-range access.

Comment: C or C++? A written, it looks like C.

Comment: Also note that `two` is `int`, which is usually larger than `char`, that could possibly lead to an out-of-range, or just not reinterpret `arr[10]` properly.

Comment: You are invoking Undefined Behaviour, and then wonder why you do not get expected results. It is just a possible outcome for UB...

Comment: @MikeCAT #pragma pack(1) does not work.I have increased the array size to 200

Comment: Well seriously, it depends on the platform: what it `sizeof(int)` on yours and are you sure that it is little endian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) UDP // (1)
{
    char one[10];
    int two;
};


int main()
{
    char arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};

    struct UDP *ptr;   //Pointer of Structure type
    ptr = (struct UDP*) arr;
    ptr->one;
    (char) ptr->two; // (2)
}
```

// (1) "int two" will be contiguos to char array "avoiding" padding rules
// (2) you have to choose only the first byte beacuse you wrote 11 as 1 byte (char)

Comment: Hi @jhowa Thank you.But adding any value after two such as ptr->three which is defined as `char three` in structure gives me an unknown value

Comment: fill the array up to 15 and keep the packed version of the struct. ptr->three will point to 15, whereas 12, 13, 14 are bytes "wasted" in the int pointer, indeed ptr->two will point at a number that is (14 << 24 | 13 << 16 | 12 << 8 | 11), when you cast to char you select the first 8 byte, so you get 11, but when you point with ptr->three, that pointer points to the next byte (because is a char pointer and the struct is packed) of the last ptr->two byte, that is 15

Answer (score 0):

```
static struct UDP
{
    char one[10];
    int two;
}p;
```

declare the object of the structure and then access two using the structure p.two

Comment: The issue isn't having an object of type UDP. It helps to read the full question. I get caught sometimes, too.

Comment: well i will look into it